# Retrieve posted parameters oauth2 (bshaffer) with access_token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am in need of API provider for my web service(databse selects/inserts, folders/files  editing/creation/delete actions etc.)

I found this library for oauth2
https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php

So far i have been able to follow the [tutorial/documentation](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/) trough and i can authenticate and access api.

Problem is that the example is simple and it does not show a way to pass in additional parameter such as mycustomaction=myustomvalue for the authenticated user.

The code that handles the resource is as follows

```
    // include our OAuth2 Server object
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';

// Handle a request to a resource and authenticate the access token
if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())) {
    $server->getResponse()->send();
    die;
}
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'You accessed my APIs!'));
```

Pseudo code of something similar that i need

```
// include our OAuth2 Server object
require_once __DIR__.'/server.php';

// Handle a request to a resource and authenticate the access token
if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())) {
    $server->getResponse()->send();
    die;
}else{
    if($customvalue){
        //get the custom value and run code for it.
    }
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'You accessed my APIs!'));   
}
```

Is there a way to do what i need with this library?

P.S. I chose this library because it was the only one that had a working tutorial that i could follow trough. I can not install additional libraries on the client side(thus the simple include file)

Answer (score 0):

the passed in extra values can be accessed like so

```
$server=OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals();
echo var_dump($server->request);
```

However i don't know how correct this solution is.